# What is the $\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{x+1}\ln\left(\sqrt{x+1}\right)} dx$?

Tags: calculus

I tried $u = \ln(\sqrt{x+1})$  so  $$2 \int \frac{1}{\ln(u)}du$$
What do yo do from here? Is there some other way?

Comment: That function doesn't seem to have an elementary anti-derivative.

Comment: In particular: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logarithmic_integral_function

Answer (score 2):

You haven't done the substitution correctly.

With $u = \ln\sqrt{x+1}$ you have $\sqrt{x+1} = e^u$ and hence $x=e^{2u}-1$, so that $dx = 2 e^{2u} du$, and your integral becomes
$$
\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{x+1} \ln\sqrt{x+1}}
= \int \frac{2 e^{2u} du}{e^u \, u}
= 2 \int \frac{e^u}{u} du
= 2 \operatorname{Ei}(u) + C
= 2 \operatorname{Ei}\Bigl(\ln\sqrt{x+1}\Bigr) + C
,
$$
where Ei is the [Exponential integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_integral).